# OpenCover running against iis

Tags: asp.net, w3wp, opencover

Is it possible to determine which application pool and port to use when running opencover against iis for w3wp?

I get error when  run this:

C:\Users\bilgevd\Desktop\KnowH\WebFoundations_v1.2.1\WebFoundations>"C:\Users\bilgevd\Desktop\KnowH\WebFoundations_v1.2.1\packages\OpenCover.4.5.2506\OpenCover.Console.exe" -target:C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -targetargs:-debug -targetdir:C:\Users\bilgevd\Desktop\KnowH\WebFoundations_v1.2.1\WebFoundations -filter:+[*]* -register:user
Executing: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Press 'Q' to shutdown the process:

Shutting down the process.

Committing...
No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common reasons are:
    1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
    output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
    2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
    guide and the -register switch.

Comment: What is in the output file? If it loaded assemblies but didn't profile them there will be a reason given in the 'skippeddueto' field

Comment: Thanks, the output file is like this.         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CoverageSession xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Summary numSequencePoints="0" visitedSequencePoints="0" numBranchPoints="0" visitedBranchPoints="0" sequenceCoverage="0" branchCoverage="0" maxCyclomaticComplexity="0" minCyclomaticComplexity="0" />
  <Modules />
</CoverageSession>

Comment: did you stop and start `w3svc` as described here - https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/147?

Comment: Yes I did. I stopped w3svc and then I runned the lines above. I got this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, I found the solution. I had to write -register:administrator instead. It now works :)